# Using AWS secrets for a glue connector in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following code in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_glue_connection" "my_connection" {
  connection_properties = {
    JDBC_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:datadirect:googlebigquery:AuthenticationMethod=serviceaccount;Project=myproject;Dataset=mydataset;ServiceAccountEmail=myemail@myproject-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com;ServiceAccountPrivateKey=/path-to/json-or-p12-file"
    PASSWORD            = "mypassword"
    USERNAME            = "myusername"
  }

  name = "my_connection"
}
```

And I want to use an AWS Secrets Manager' secret, to avoid hardcoding password and username. But when I tried this:

```
data "aws_secretmanager_secret" "example" {
  name = "example-secret"
}
```

It won't refer to my already created secrets. Please, could you help me pointing out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an error message? Is there something to illustrate desired versus actual behavior?

Comment: "It won't refer to my already created secrets." Please edit your question to show the *actual* error message, exactly as it is. If there is no error message, then edit your question in much more detail to describe how you have tried linking the `aws_secretmanager_secret` data source to the `aws_glue_connection` resource.

Comment: Import the secret. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret#import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first at all create your db credentials

[image]

[image]

next try to get your secret credential from tf code
[image]

code example:

```
 data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "password" {
  name = "db-credential"
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "password" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.password.id
}
output "get-secret" {
  sensitive = true
  value = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password.secret_string)["password"] 
}

resource "aws_glue_connection" "my_connection" {
  connection_properties = {
    JDBC_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:datadirect:googlebigquery:AuthenticationMethod=serviceaccount;Project=myproject;Dataset=mydataset;ServiceAccountEmail=myemail@myproject-12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com;ServiceAccountPrivateKey=/path-to/json-or-p12-file"
    PASSWORD            = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password.secret_string)["password"]
    USERNAME            = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password.secret_string)["username"]
  }

  name = "my_connection"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dayron, great answer!, please, then, how can I bring that value to the required connection? Would it be: `PASSWORD = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password.secret_string)["password"]` in the Glue connection section?

Comment: hi @Alexis glad to be helpful for you. Yes in your case you can do that: PASSWORD = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password.secret_string)["password"]  to assign password in your connection credentials. Please let me know

Comment: great!, it is what I needed... and your answer was detailed and high quality. Have a great day!

Comment: @DayronRemigio  could you add a glue connection example tf code snippet to see how to use it?

Comment: Hi @safex I edited the solution with a code sniped for testing the database credential. Would you test that and give me feedback? I am so glad to collaborate with you

Comment: i had the same thing but it didn't work for me -- but I had the incorrect secret name. I am sure this will help others find it directly